# How to read a lot of DICOM files with Matlab?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, dicom

I am using a script which generate a collection of strings in a loop:

```
'folder1/im1' 
'folder1/im2'
... 
'folder1/im3'
```

I assign the string to a variable, when I try to execute the `img = dicomread(file);` function I get the following error:

```
Error using dicomread>newDicomread (line 164)
The first input argument must be a filename or DICOM info struct.

Error in dicomread (line 80)
[X, map, alpha, overlays] = newDicomread(msgname, frames);

Error in time (line 14)
    img = dicomread(file);
```

However, using the command line I don't get errors: `img = dicomread('folder1/im1')`.

The code is the next:

```
    for i=1:6 %six cases
            nameDir = strcat('folder', int2str(i));
            dirData = dir(nameDir);
            dirIndex = [dirData.isdir];
            fileList = {dirData(~dirIndex).name}; % list of files for each directory
            n = size(fileList);
            cd(nameDir);
            for x = 1:n(2)
                    img = dicomread(strcat(pwd(), '/', fileList(x)));
            end
            cd('..');
    end
```

What could be the error?

Comment: Are the paths absolute? If not, check the paths relative to the script location?

Comment: @Ansari I tested with both: absolute paths and relative paths...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've figured it out by now, haven't you.

Based on what you've written, you test

```
img = dicomread('folder1/im1');
```

when what you are having trouble with is

```
img = dicomread(file);
```

You need to actually test the line you are having trouble with.  I would recommend:

> putting a break point in test.m a the line `img = dicomread(file)`.  When you get to that line you can see what `file` is equal to.  Also do `whos file` to make sure it is  of class `char` and not a cell array or something random.

If you still want help, edit your original post and show the code where you assign those strings to `file` and tell us what happens when you type `img = dicomread(file)` at the command prompt.

Comment: `img = dicomread(char(strcat(pwd(), '/', fileList(x))));` You rock, I converted `class cell` to `class char` with `char()` function.